# Hackerrank The subarray sums question - time out test cases

Tags: algorithm

Here is one question from hackerrank, I have a solution but there is some testcase failed because time limit exceeded. I don't know the better solution for it.

Find Sum of elements in a subarray (if in subarray has 0, sum = sum + number x)

input:
numbers: main array(1-indexed)

queries:

```
   array of query: left index, right index, number x(0-indexed)
```

output:

array of sum corresponding with queries.

my solution on C++ code:

```
vector<long> findSum(vector<int>numbers, vector<vector<int>> queries)
{
   vector<long>result;
   long sum = 0;
   int count = 0;
   for(auto i : queries)
   {
      sum = 0;
      count = 0;
      int l = i[0] - 1;
      int r = i[1]-1;
      int x = i[2];
      for(int j =l; j<r;j++)
      {
         sum+=numbers[j]==0?x:numbers[j]; 
      }
      result.push_back(sum);
   }
   return result;
}
```

Comment: I have faced this question too and did the same (brute force), after a quick search I guess optimized algorithm can be built with a segment tree. https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/notes/segment-tree-and-lazy-propagation/

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum

Comment: Can you please share the link to a problem?

Comment: @ashishpandey its problem of "basic problem-solving skill test", so link can't be shared.

Answer (score 6):

As suggested by @Annity, you need to maintain two arrays:

1. Sum of all numbers so far. At any point of the index, it should have the sum of all previous numbers.
2. Same as above but it should have the total count of all previous Zeros.

You should avoid nested loops to reduce time complexity. Here is a solution in javascript:

```js
function  findSum(numbers,  queries)  {

  let  result  =   [];    
  let  subArraySum  =   [];    
  let  countZero  =  numbers[0]  ==  0  ?  1  :  0;    
  let  zeroArr  =   [];    
  zeroArr[0] =  countZero;    
  subArraySum[0]  =  numbers[0];    
  for (let  i = 1;  i <=  numbers.length - 1;  i++)  {               
    if (numbers[i]  ==  0) {            
      countZero++;            
      zeroArr[i]  =  countZero;        
    } 
    else  {            
      zeroArr[i]  =  countZero;         
    }         
    subArraySum[i]  = subArraySum[i - 1]  +  numbers[i];    
  }    

  for (let  q  of  queries)  {            
    if (q.length  ==  3)  {            
      let  i  =  q[0];            
      let  j  =  q[1];            
      let  x  =  q[2];            
      let  sum  =  0;                       
      sum  =  subArraySum[j - 1] - ((i - 2  <  0 )  ?  0  :  subArraySum[i - 2]);             
      sum  =  sum  +  (zeroArr[j - 1] - ((i - 2  <  0 )  ?  0  :  zeroArr[i - 2])) * x;            
      result.push(sum);        
    }                  
  }    
  return  result;
}
console.log(findSum([5, 10, 15], [
  [1, 2, 5]
]))
console.log(findSum([0, 10, 15], [
  [1, 2, 5]
]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution that occurred to me.

You need to create two new arrays - one for the sums and one for the number of zeroes. Eg. `sums[]` and `zeroes[]`.

In these two arrays you will store the value for the sum and the number of zeroes from the first element to the current. This is how it goes:

Loop through all of the numbers.

For each number with index `i` save in `sums[i]` the cumulative sum of all the elements from the first to the current and in `zeroes[i]` - the number of zeroes from the first element to the current.

Then loop through all of the queries.

For every query calculate the sum:

You take the sum from the sums array for the element with the right index and deduct the sum for the element before the left index.
(`sum = sums[r] - sums[l-1]`)

If you deduct the count of zeroes in the element before the left index from the number in the element on the right index - you will get the number of zeroes in the interval.
(`zero = zeroes[r] - zeroes[l-1]`)

Then multiply it by the third element in the query and add it to the sum.

And this is how you have the sum for the query.

Answer (score 1):

this is in python

```
tempRes=0
    temp = []
    for b in range(len(queries)):
        for k in range(queries[b][0]-1,queries[b][1]):
            if numbers[k] == 0:
                tempRes = tempRes + queries[b][2]
            tempRes = tempRes + numbers[k]
        temp.append(tempRes)
        tempRes = 0
        

    return temp
```

Answer (score 1):

***JS Solution:***

There are two methods to solve this problem (Brute force Solution [Nested Loop]) and that's the method that responds with a timeout error throughout the execution of the test, you need to solve it with another time complexity, here is my answer 1st method O(N^2) and then 2nd method Optimized to be O(N) to solving the timeout error.

**Answers in JavaScript wish it helps you.**

```js
/*
-- Brainstorming --

    Have 1-indexed Array [numbers] of length n;
    Have numbers of queries (q). [2D Array]
    Each Query => [startIdx i, endIdx r, number x]

    Find => Sum of numbers between indexes i and r (both included)
    if zero occured in range add x instead of it.
*/

// 1st Method: Brute force Solution [Nested Loop]

function findSum(numbers, queries) {
    const sum = new Array(queries.length).fill(0);

    for (let i = 0; i < queries.length; i++) {
        // let j = queries[i][0] - 1 Cause numbers 1-index not 0
        for (let j = queries[i][0] - 1; j < queries[i][1]; j++) {
            if (numbers[j] === 0) {
                sum[i] += queries[i][2];
            } else {
                sum[i] += numbers[j];
            }
        }
    }

    return sum;
}



// 2nd Method: The Optimized Solution Single Loop

function findSum(numbers, queries) {
    const sums = [];
    const subArraySum = [];
    const zerosArr = [];
    let zerosCount = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] === 0) {
            zerosCount++;
            zerosArr[i] = zerosCount;
        } else {
            zerosArr[i] = zerosCount;
        }
        subArraySum[i] = numbers[i] + (subArraySum[i - 1] || 0);
    }
    for (let q of queries) {
        const i = q[0] - 1;
        const r = q[1] - 1;
        const x = q[2];
        let finalSum = subArraySum[r] - (subArraySum[i - 1] || 0) + (zerosArr[r] - (zerosArr[i - 1] || 0)) * x;
        sums.push(finalSum);
    }
    return sums;
}

console.log("1st Test: " + findSum([5,10,10], [[1,2,5]])) // 15
console.log("2nd Test: " + findSum([-5,0], [ [2, 2 ,20] , [1,2,10]])) // 20 , 5
console.log("3rd Test: " + findSum([-1,-1,1,-4,3,-3,-4], [ [1, 4 ,2]])) // -5
console.log("4th Test: " + findSum([1000000000], [[1, 1,100]]))// 1000000000
console.log("5th Test: " + findSum([-1000000000], [[1, 1,100]]))// -1000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code takes a linear time per query. Invest in a linear time *once* to precompute an array of partial sums. Then each query will be answered in a constant time.

Comment: This does not give any idea, can you elaborate with a pseudocode?

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static List<Long> findSum(List<Integer> numbers, List<List<Integer>> queries) {
    // Write your code here
    ArrayList<Long> arr = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < queries.size(); i++) {
        int sum = 0;

        for(int j = queries.get(i).get(0) - 1; j <= queries.get(i).get(1) - 1; j++) {
            if(numbers.get(j) == 0){
                sum += queries.get(i).get(2);
            } else {
                sum += numbers.get(j);
            }
        }

        arr.add((long)sum);
        sum = 0;
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Try to add some explanation or logic for your code rather than providing only the code

Answer (score 0):

The logic tries to sum each index with the last index.
But initializes the first index with 0.
The same with counting the zero.
After that, just subtract the left side with the desired index.
Also with the zero value in the index, but multiplid by the queries.
There you have it. I can't post the answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Solution in `C`
Pass All tests and time limits

Code is over commented, so it is better to read it on `C` compiler/editor

Simply you must avoid nested loops, try to do repeated work ONCE, use accumelated sume technique as illustrated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


long* findSum(int numbers_count, int* numbers, int queries_rows, int queries_columns, int** queries, int* result_count) {
    //Dynamically create an array of longs to store the results and initialize it to 0 each element using calloc()
    long * ResArray = (long*)calloc(queries_rows , (sizeof (long)));
    //Dynamically create an array of longs to store accumelated zero counts, this array will exceed the size of numbers array by 1
    //as the first element will be 0 and the last element will be the accumelated zero count of the numbers array
    // numbers[] ->      1,0,2,0,0,3,5,0
    // zeroFlagArr[] ->  0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4
    long * zeroFlagArr = (long*)calloc(numbers_count+1 , (sizeof (long)));
    //same as the zeroFlagArr but this array will store the accumelated sum of the numbers array
    // numbers[] ->      1,0,2,0,0,3,5,0
    // prefix_sum[] ->   0,1,1,3,3,3,6,11,11
    long* prefix_sum = (long*) malloc((numbers_count + 1) * sizeof(long));
    zeroFlagArr[0] =0;//first element of zeroFlagArr is 0, as nothing before index 0 in numbers[] to consider !
    prefix_sum[0] = 0;//first element of prefix_sum is 0, as nothing before index 0 in numbers[] to sum up !
    //loop through the numbers array and fill the zeroFlagArr and prefix_sum arrays
    //this is done one time only every function call to be used in the queries loop
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers_count; i++) {
        //if currnet numbers[] element == 0, then the next element in the zeroFlagArr will be the previous element + 1
        //note here we exceed i by one for both arrays as we accumelate what is behine in numbers[] array
        if (numbers[i]== 0) {
            zeroFlagArr[i+1] = zeroFlagArr[i] +1;
        }
        //else if it is any other number, then just use the last index value
        else{
            zeroFlagArr[i+1] = zeroFlagArr[i];
        }
        //fill the prefix_sum array with the accumelated sum of the numbers array
        prefix_sum[i + 1] = prefix_sum[i] + numbers[i];
    }
    //loop the queries input 
    for (int i = 0 ; i <queries_rows  ; i++) { 

        int startIndex = (queries[i][0] -1);// -1 because the input is indexing from 1 not 0
        int endIndex = (queries[i][1] -1);// -1 because the input is indexing from 1 not 0

        //index             0 ,1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,6 ,7 ,8 ,9 ,10,11,12
        // numbers[] ->     1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,0 ,5 ,0 ,6 ,8 ,0 ,0 ,9
        //                    |<-------[1] to [9]------->|  
        // prefix_sum[] ->  0 ,1 ,3 ,6 ,10,15,15,20,20,26,34,34,34,43
        //              sum+= |<-------[10]-[1]------------>|                         
        // zeroFlagArr[] -> 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,2 ,2 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,4
        //              sum+= |<----{(2)-(0)} x load------->|
        long sum = prefix_sum[endIndex + 1] - prefix_sum[startIndex];
        sum += ((zeroFlagArr[endIndex+1] - zeroFlagArr[startIndex]) * queries[i][2] );  
        ResArray[i] =  sum;       
    } 
    free(prefix_sum);

    *result_count = queries_rows;
    return ResArray;
}

int main()
{
    int numbers_count = 2;
    int numbers[] = {-5,0};
    int queries_rows = 2;
    int queries_columns = 3;

    int **queries = (int**)malloc(queries_rows * sizeof(int*));
    for (int i = 0; i < queries_rows; i++)
        queries[i] = (int*)malloc(queries_columns * sizeof(int));
    
    queries[0][0] = 2;
    queries[0][1] = 2;
    queries[0][2] = 20;
    queries[1][0] = 1;
    queries[1][1] = 2;
    queries[1][2] = 10;

    int result_count;
    long* result = findSum(numbers_count, numbers, queries_rows, queries_columns, queries, &result_count);
    for (int i = 0; i < result_count; i++) {
        printf("%ld \n", result[i]);
    }
    scanf( "%d" , &result_count);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this(in javascript):

```js
function findSum(numbers, queries) {
  // Write your code here
  let sumArr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < queries.length; i++) {
    let sum = 0;
    let start = queries[i][0];
    let end = queries[i][1] + 1;
    let x = queries[i][2];

    const newArr = numbers.slice(start, end);

    newArr.forEach((item) => {
      if (item === 0) {
        sum = sum + x;
      }
      sum = sum + item;
    });
    sumArr.push(sum);
  }
  return sumArr;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3


def solution(numbers, queries):
    if not isinstance(numbers, list) and not isinstance(queries, list):
        return
    result = []
    total = 0
    for query in queries:
        if len(query) == 3:
            start = query[0]
            end = query[1]
            additional = query[2]
            selection = numbers[start-1:end]
            has_zeros = False
            for el in selection:
                if el == 0:
                    has_zeros = True
            print(f"has_zeros: {has_zeros}")
            print(f"selection: {selection}")
            total = sum(selection)
            if has_zeros:
                total += additional
            result.append(total)
    return result


if "__main__" == __name__:
    # 15
    _input = [5, 10, 10]
    _queries = [[1], [3], [1, 2, 5]]
    print(f"input: {_input}")
    print(f"queries: {_queries}")
    _output = solution(_input, _queries)
    print(f"ouput: {_output}")
```

Comment: It's simply a piece of code, without any explaination

Answer (score -1):

Solution in python3 :

```
def findSum(numbers, queries):
    a = [0]
    b = [0]
    for x in numbers:
        a.append(a[-1] + x)
        b.append(b[-1] + (x == 0)) if in subarray has 0, sum = sum + number x)
    return [a[r] - a[l - 1] + x * (b[r] - b[l - 1]) for l, r, x in queries]
```